# Status of GeoRSS Simple?

Tags: data, georss, rdf, owl

I'm currently looking to contribute to a project which seeks to integrate GeoRSS RDF properties, and I'm struggling to find precisely where there exists an OWL Document for the ontology itself.

It appears as if the link to the mailing list for the project is dead:

http://www.georss.org/implementations.html

Are they still actively supporting RDF properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think georss rdf was ever completed. If you look on the [page](http://www.georss.org/rdf_rss1.html) it contains the line:

> This material is preliminary and only for discussion at this time.